# Why RequestBody won't bind into my java model?

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring

What i trying to do here is binding a JSON value into my java Model with RequestBody, but it won't bind into my java model. Here is my code :

Here is my HelloController.java

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/transaksi/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> simpanKupon(@RequestBody TransaksiKupon transaksi, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

        String a = "asdf";

/*        if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
            System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getNM_TOKO() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }*/

        transaksiService.saveKupon(transaksi);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        /*headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/login").buildAndExpand(transaksi.getKodevoucher()).toUri());*/
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

i use POST as the request method, but it's not working, the "transaksi" model is null

but when i use GET as the requestmethod, it work properly. Here is my code in another controller :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/transaksi/{KODEVOUCHER}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<TransaksiKupon> getValidasi(@PathVariable("KODEVOUCHER") String KODEVOUCHER) {


        TransaksiKupon trxKupon = transaksiService.validasi(KODEVOUCHER);
        if (trxKupon.getKODEVOUCHER() != null){
            return new ResponseEntity<TransaksiKupon>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        /*if (trxkupon == null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + KODEVOUCHER + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<TransaksiKupon>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }*/

        return new ResponseEntity<TransaksiKupon>(trxKupon,HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

it just work properly. And here is my angularjs code while submiting the form, app.js :

```
'use strict';

App2.factory('KuponService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    return {

        simpanKupon: function(transaksi){
            alert(JSON.stringify(transaksi));
            return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/webbass/transaksi/', transaksi)
                    .then(
                            function(response){
                                return response.data;
                            }, 
                            function(errResponse){
                                console.error('Error while save transaksi');
                                return $q.reject(errResponse);
                            }
                    );
        },

        validasiKupon: function(transaksi){
            /*var KODEVOUCHER = transaksi.KODEVOUCHER;*/
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/webbass/transaksi/'+transaksi)
                    .then(

                            function(response){
                                return response.data;
                            }, 
                            function(errResponse){
                                console.error('Tidak ada Nomor Kupon ini');
                                return $q.reject(errResponse);

                            }
                    );
        }


    };

}]);
```

Here is my dependancy:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

What i missed here?? i am stuck almost a week, help me!

Comment: I would suggest to check in Chrome or Firefox console in Network tab  if this parameter is indeed sent. By doing this you'll be sure on which side you have a problem.

Comment: Try without `/` at the end of the path : `transaksi` instead of `transaksi/`

Comment: no it give me this error when i look into console, it said "415 unsupported media type" what's that mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have dependency of your parser - jackson in this case, but you have to annotate your body object with Jackson Annotstions or configure parser for app in application.yml if you use Spring Boot  the it will parse by field names.

Comment: it give me this error when i look into console and network, it said "415 unsupported media type" what's that mean? i don't use spring boot

Comment: then try to use consumes="application/json" in you request mapping

Comment: It means that your controller is not ready to get such format as you send in content-type header

Comment: Content type is mime type which describes your request body file type and your controller must be ready to consume such format also chceck if your requests to backend has such one to simplify testing u can use Google Chrome plugin Rest Controller Api paste json into, change header to "application/json" a hit your localhost service .